# How do I show the values of each array element?

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a function that is supposed to return an array of errors to validate a form. I have tried to accomplish this a few ways, but problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to display the error messages.

I've tried

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($errors); $i++)
{
    echo ($errors[$i]);
}
```

and

```
foreach($errors as $err)
{
    echo($err);
}
```

Both of these seem to give me the same result: "ArrayArray".

If I use  `var_dump()` it does show that the array has values.

I feel like this has a very simple solution, but I have been searching for quite a while and trying to modify this anyway I can think of with no result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a multi dimensional array. Assuming you have 2d array you would.

```
foreach($errors as $err)
{
    foreach($err as $err2)
        echo($err2);
}
```

or old style

```
foreach($errors as $i => $err)
{
    foreach($err as $errKey => $errVal)
        echo($errVal);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by old style?

Comment: the second one was used a lot until php came with a short hand method which is the first version. They both do the same,  but sometime the old style is much more clear.

Comment: The only difference I see is that you are also refering the keys in stead of only the values. It depends on if you need the keys also when you decide which variant to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print_r( $errors );`. Works for arrays, objects etc.

@comment
Looking at what print_r shows your table definition is quite weird. To list error msgs you need:

```
 foreach( $errors[2] as $err )
   echo $err."<br />";
```

Comment: I've tried this as well and it still doesn't show just the error message. @David added to your suggestion and I commented below with what the output was of `print_r()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayErrors($errors)
{
   if(is_array($errors)){
     foreach($errors as $error)
     {
       displayErrors($error);
     }
   }
   else{
        echo($errors);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the suggestion by @piotrm - you get nicely readable output if you wrap your `print_r()` call in `<pre>...</pre>` tags:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($errors); ?>
</pre>
```

It is at least the easiest solution!

Comment: I've tried
`echo "<pre>";
echo print_r("$errors");
echo "</pre>";`
but it just displays
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => 
            [2] => Please enter your first name.
            [3] => Please enter your last name.
            [4] => Please enter a valid email address.
            [5] => Please enter a user name.
            [6] => Please enter a valid username.
            [7] => Password must be at least 4 characters long.
        )

)
`.

Comment: @Kevin - What's the nature of your environment? If you're not getting line returns while with the `pre` tags, there must be something odd, I would guess. At least there is no need for `echo` with ` print_r`. You could also have a look at the [PHP manual for ` print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) where many [user contributed comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#87418) also feature `pre` tags. If you're looking for something really funky, there's also [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/). Hope that helps!

Comment: Also - there's no need for the quote marks around the array variable: just: `print_r($errors);`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why the code in my comment is messed up, in my actual code I'm not using an `echo` with the `print_r()` and I don't have quotation marks around the array variable. I'm guessing I messed up when copying/pasting somehow... Anyways, I'll take a look at your links and see if I can find anything else, I will probably just end up changing how I do this error list because I need to get this done soon and I think I'm just making a dumb mistake somewhere that I can't pinpoint. You've been a lot of help though, I appreciate it!